# Dutch formula not working in english Excel version

Tags: excel-formula

Need help with a dutch formula not working in english Excel.

For some reason the formula below doesn't work with the english version of Excel, can someone help me with this? I'm left with this error `#NAME?`

```
=SPATIES.WISSEN(WISSEN.CONTROL((SUBSTITUEREN(A1;TEKEN(160);" "))))
```

Does not work still results in `#NAME?`:

```
=TRIM(CLEAN((SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(160);" "))))
```

Comment: you will need to find what the english version of that formula is.  There are many sites that will help translate each part to what it should be in English.  This is not a translation service. [HERE](https://www.perfectxl.com/excel-glossary/what-is-excel-function/translations-english-dutch/) is one.

Comment: I tried that and it diddn't work.

Comment: Then please [edit] the post to include the English version you tried.

Comment: Updated with english formula

Comment: Try changing the `;` to `,` in EN-US format we use `,` not `;`

Comment: @ScottCraner - sorry posted answer at same time as your comment, lmk and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @MikeMiller it may be the answer.  If it is indeed the correct answer, I would add a blurb about local settings being the reason one would need to use something other than `;` as the delineator.

Comment: ; seems to work fine in the english variant of Excel for me tho.

Comment: Then it is hard to figure out the reason.  The formula works for us.  There must be something else that we can only guess at.

Comment: And A1 does not have an error in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got semi colons not commas in the formula

=TRIM(CLEAN((SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160), " "))))

works fine for me.

From @Scott Craner - it appears that local settings may stop ; being used as a separator for variables in the method call, and , should work.

Comment: If I do this I get an error that there is something wrong with the formula

Comment: Can you download this Excel and see if it works for you? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p7e3ihoha6fb3mbWjl38gfukyeIa_4g3/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104123395356979725885&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Select File > Download > XLSX